# Mounted folder in GCP Jupyter Notebook does not show files within the mounted folder

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I am training a model on GCP using a VM instance and I have my folder with 3 directories full of images. I am building a Deep Learning model using this data and am trying to set the path to the directory with the images.

It says the files have been mounted
[image]

But when I check the size of the folder it does not match the actual 20GB size as in my GCP Bucket. Also when I try to check the files in the mounted folder the whole notebook just crashes and I have to redo everything again.
[image]

Comment: Looks like a permission issue. Can you check if the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable is set and you're using a service account that allows you to read/write files?.

Comment: I set the application credentials but did not set the service account. Should I list myself as the project owner? I can't seem to find where it specifically allows me to read or write files.

Comment: You need to create a service account in IAM to mount the bucket as as filesystem. It should have at least read permission (unless you want to write).

Comment: Hey I did that but still the same issue. When I open the JupyterLab would it ask for a key to use the notebook? Cause it does not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Iñigo mentioned I needed to set the service account and the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable.